# Getting error when start my ADT 22.2.1.201309180102-833290

Tags: android

After updating my Android SDK Manager, getting error prompt mentioned as current version of ADT is 22.2.1.201309180102-833290, update it to 23.0. When I searched for updates, I got "No update found" prompt. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: remove the old version and reinstall it again. There is some problem with this upgrade

Comment: it happens to me also so i downloaded a fresh copy of software.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an earlier update to ADT plugin. What I did was:

- Go to Help -> Install new Software...
- Paste the following URL in the Work with box : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Wait for the download to complete.
- Restart your IDE.

Comment: I am getting:    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290

Comment: Then try removing the current version ADT plugin i.e. 22.x.x.x and try again.